# Difference between vFabric RabbitMQ and plain old RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, vmware

What are the key differences between the vFabric RabbitMQ and RabbitMQ besides that vFabric is commercially supported by VMWare?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [source](https://www.rabbitmq.com/services.html):

> We also produce a commercially licensed release of RabbitMQ under the
>   vFabric™ brand. This includes all of the features of the open source
>   version and contains additional commercially focused components.
>   Support agreements are also available from Pivotal for vFabric
>   RabbitMQ.

So basically, it's pretty much the same other than just nice packaged version together with all the other Pivotal suite of software (that may be commercial or open source). RabbitMQ is under Apache license so it needs to abide to its "open sourceness". Pivotal provides consulting and training on its products and that's where the bulk of their income comes from. Another similar example is [Cloudera](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/home.html) which follows the same model.

Comment: so it means when I buy vFabric RabbitMQ, I'm just buying some support?

Comment: Yeah and all the other "components" that come with it, for example if you buy the Pivotal suite. You can tell that they are not very clear on their website as they want to sell you the support. Also they have a per CPU limit and that's so they can support you.

Comment: The ASL does not enforce "open sourceness" - it allows binary only distribution.